# CLLocation Manager delegate issues

Tags: ios, objective-c, geolocation, cllocationmanager

Please can anyone try to help me on this issue.
I have one requirement like, I want to call a class method from static constructor `(+(id)initialize)` method like below that will `intialize` the `CLLocationmanager`. 
My problem is how can I give a delegate in that class method and how to get delegates method called.

```
+(void)initialize 
{ 
    [self fetchLocation]; 
}

+(void)fetchLocation
{
 mLocation = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init]; 
 mLocation.delegate = self;
 mLocation.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
 [mLocation startUpdatingLocation]; 
}
```

If I allocate the same class instance and add as delegate its crashing.

Answer (score 2):

1) You can't call `[self fetchLocation]` from a static method like `+initialize`. That's because there's no `self` there (`self` refers to the current object, which is something you don't have in static methods.)

2) The line `mLocation.delegate = self` doesn't make sense for the same reason.

To fix your design, you can do one of the following things, depending on what makes the most sense in your app:

- Make your class a singleton, and make that singleton a delegate for `CLLocationManager`
- Put the location manager init code in the appropriate `-init` method of your class